# pymongo - how to insert a new filed in an exist table

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I would like to know how can I update an exist table into Mongodb using pymongo python library.

Example, I have this dictionary:

`dict1 = [{'A': 11, 'B': 999}, {'A': 22, 'B': 888}]`

And I can insert it into a Mongodb using it:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client=MongoClient('mongodb://root:xxxxx@10.240.50.181:30006/?authSource=admin&readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&ssl=false')
db=client['controlesBBTX']
colect=db.teste_Anselmo
colect.insert_many(dict1)
```

Result:

`A     B`

`11    999`

`22    888`

This code above works fine, and now I want to insert this another dict into the same table before, like inserting a new row:

`dict2 = [{'A': 333, 'B': 444}]`

Expected:

`A     B`

`11    999`

`22    888`

`333    444`

Comment: Simply do the same again, what is the problem?

Comment: Thanks man... I don´t know why, but I did it so many time before and nothing happens... Now works fine. Thanks.